# Can SharePoint 2010 be used to authenticate external web form?

Tags: claims-based-auth, sharepoint-server, adfs, secure-store, sts

I am tasked at creating a SSO solution. I have webform on `a.example.com`, SharePoint on `b.example.com`. SharePoint uses claims based auth, and uses ADFS as the idP.

Can the claims based webform use the sharepoint STS and Secure store, so login is not required after they have already logged in to Sharepoint?

I should mention, for some reason they do not to have the webform authenticate directly through the adfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the claims based webform use the sharepoint STS and Secure store, so login is not required after they have already logged in to Sharepoint?

No, what you should do is use ADFS for authentication in your web forms app. If you run FedUtil and configure your web forms app it'll wire up all you need.

SharePoint routes to ADFS, so your custom web forms app should use the same.

The Secure Store Service is only really used to store things like Credentials, and nothing really (aside from Excel Services) can use it for authentication.